# method_missing Within instance_eval

Tags: ruby

Full code: http://friendpaste.com/5TdtGPZaEK0DbDBa2DCUyB

```
class Options
    def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
        p method
    end
end

options = Options.new

options.instance_eval do
    foo
    foo = "It aint easy being cheesy!"
end

puts "#===---"
options.foo
options.foo = "It still aint easy being cheesy!"
```

This returns:

```
:foo
#===---
:foo
:foo=
```

Because it is treating `foo = ""` as a local variable within instance_eval, it's not recognize it as a method.

How would I make instance_eval treat it as a method?

Comment: what do you want 'options.foo="it aint . . . "' to do?

Comment: To be captured within method_missing for me to manipulate it, specifically to set a key/value in a hash. It'll kinda work like a Struct.

Comment: Check out the full code (link at the top of post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `foo = ""` will never be a method call. It is a local variable assignment. This is a fact of Ruby's syntax. In order to call a setter, you have to specify a receiver explicitly. This is why most Ruby pseudo-DSLs use the Dwemthy-style:

```
class Dragon < Creature
  life 1340     # tough scales
  strength 451  # bristling veins
  charisma 1020 # toothy smile
  weapon 939    # fire breath
end
```

That avoids the equals sign problem.

Comment: Oh geez, why didn't I think of this? Thats perfect =D

Answer (score 2):

Do `self.foo = ""` to make it treat it as a method.

Comment: Yeah, that would work I suppose. But the reason I'm trying to figure this out is so I don't have to use self.foo or options.tap { |o| o.foo } to run methods =/

Comment: Here is my full code, if you are intersted: http://friendpaste.com/5TdtGPZaEK0DbDBa2DCUyB

Comment: Sadly, I don't think it is possible. `foo =` will always be interpreted as a local variable assignment and there is no way of getting to local variables defined inside a block.

Comment: It seems even `foo=()` will not work. Oh well, I guess I will have to do it your way. Thanks